# get entire folders/files tree and rename

Tags: php, rename, glob

I have a folders/files tree inside `admin` folder (windows, localhost).

All files are `.html`.

Each of them (files and folders) is starting with some numbers and middle dash, for example

`32-somefolder`
`624-somefile.html`

I need to list all of them and remove all prefixes from their names.
So the result should be:

`somefolder`
`somefile.html`

```
foreach(glob("admin/*") as $el) {
        echo $el . '.' . filetype($el) . '<br>';
    }
```

First problem - only folders are listed:

`admin/32-somefolder.dir`

How to get files too, and how to rename i.e. remove prefixes from all the names?

Comment: For the list: http://php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php

and when you'll have the list (with paths) you can use the rename function http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: scandir() (will give you an array of files and dirs including . and ..) and then some more logic to strip the prefix...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second choice to list files : `scandir`, and recursive function :

```
function removePrefixFiles($dir, &$results = array()){
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($files as $key => $value){
        $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        if (! is_dir($path)) {
            // treat the filename
            $file = pathinfo($path);
            $filename = explode('-', $file['filename']);

            if (count($filename) > 0) {
                // '-' is found, rename file
                rename($path, $file['dirname'] .'/'. $filename[1] .'.'. $file['extension'];
            }
            $results[] = $path;
        } else if ($value != '.' && $value != '..') {
            removePrefixFiles($path, $results);
            $results[] = $path;
        }
    }

    // no real need to return something here, but can log the files
    return $results;
}

$dir = '/admin';
removePrefixFiles($dir);
```

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getDirContents()`

Comment: Doesn't work. no one prefix is removed. Just all files are moved from all nested folders to `admin`. Please, try.

Answer (score 0):

**I have created two folder inside admin/ name as**

1-files and 2-abc

**then inside folder 1-files i have two files**

11-java.html

11-text.html

**then inside folder 2-abc i have two files**

22-php.html

22-sql.html

```
<?php 
$dir = "admin/";

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
$a = scandir($dir);
echo "<pre>";
if(count($a)>0){
    $newArr = array();
    for($i=2;$i<count($a);$i++){
        $test = array();
        $folderArr = array();
        $folderName = explode('-',$a[$i]);
        $test['folder'] = $folderName[1];
        $b = scandir($dir.'/'.$a[$i]);

        for($j=2;$j<count($b);$j++){
            $fileName    =  explode('-',$b[$j]);
            $folderArr[] = substr($fileName[1], 0, strpos($fileName[1], "."));;
        }

        $test['files'] = $folderArr;
        $newArr[] = $test;
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
?>
```

**This will be the output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [folder] => files
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => java
                    [1] => text
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [folder] => abc
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => php
                    [1] => sql
                )

        )

)
```

Hope this willl hellp you.